# Avoid Gmail API daily limit of 1000 emails per day?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I have successfully implemented with Gmail's api to send emails via the client through other programs.  Very useful, awesome, and satisfying to accomplish.

However, the Gmail API has a daily limit of 1000 emails that you can send using the API.  Is there a way around this limit, through batching or otherwise?

Thanks,

Brad

Answer (score 0):

Nope and it's not just an API limit, it's a Gmail-wide limit through web and SMTP MSA.  Spammers: this is why we can't have nice things.